# keyword "it" is showing error in kotlin code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This code was written before inside oncreate it was working fine but when i shifted it down in order to create a function this "it" is showing these errors, i had checked there is no variable like "it"

this is the code

```
  if (manager.getInt("limitOfBox") > 0) {
        Bloom.with(this)
            .setParticleRadius(5f)
            .setEffector(
                BloomEffector.Builder()
                    .setDuration(1500)
                    .setAnchor(
                        (it.width / 2).toFloat(),
                        (it.height / 2).toFloat()
                    )
                    .build()
            )
            .boom(it)
```

and these are the errors, "it" is turned red

[image]

[image]

[image]

so please tell me what to write instead of "it" , so that it don't throw errors.

this is the old code which was working perfectly :-

```
class LuckyBoxActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var binding: ActivityLuckyBoxBinding
lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
lateinit var myRepo: MyRepo
lateinit var manager: PrefManager
val activity = this

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityLuckyBoxBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    showProgress()

    var winningCoins = 0
    var limit = 0

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    myRepo = MyRepo(this)
    manager = PrefManager(this)

    loadBanner()




    db.collection("Earning").document("box")
        .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if (error == null) {
                val data = value?.toObject(WatchVideoModel::class.java)
                winningCoins = data?.winningCoins.toString().toInt()
                limit = data?.limit.toString().toInt()

                Log.e("luck Box", "onCreate: $winningCoins")
                Log.e("luck Box", "onCreate: $limit")

                if (manager.getInt("limitOfBox") == 102) {
                    binding.limit.text = "$limit"
                    manager.setInt("limitOfBox", limit)
                } else {
                    binding.limit.text = manager.getInt("limitOfBox").toString()
                }
                dismissProgress()
            }
        }



    binding.giftImg.setOnClickListener {



        val winningAmount = (0..winningCoins).random()

        if (manager.getInt("limitOfBox") > 0) {
            Bloom.with(this)
                .setParticleRadius(5f)
                .setEffector(
                    BloomEffector.Builder()
                        .setDuration(1500)
                        .setAnchor(
                            (it.width / 2).toFloat(),
                            (it.height / 2).toFloat()
                        )
                        .build()
                )
                .boom(it)

            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(Runnable {
                binding.giftImg.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }, 1000)
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(Runnable {

                manager.setInt("limitOfBox", manager.getInt("limitOfBox") - 1)
                binding.limit.text = manager.getInt("limitOfBox").toString()

                binding.resultText.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                if (winningAmount == 0) {
                    binding.resultText.text =
                        "Oops !! better luck next time..."
                } else {
                    binding.resultText.text = "$winningAmount Coins"
                    myRepo.addCoins(winningAmount.toString().toDouble())
                }
            }, 1500)

        } else {
            showToast("Daily Limit Over")
        }
    }
}

fun loadBanner() {
    val view = BannerView(this@LuckyBoxActivity, constants.banner, UnityBannerSize(320, 50))
    view.load()
    binding.bannerAd.addView(view)
}
companion object {
    private const val TAG = "LuckyBoxActivity"
}
```

}

Comment: i tried using "this" also instead of "it" but then width and height turned red

Comment: We need to see more of the context of the original code to see what `it` was referring to.

Comment: it refers to `binding.giftImg` in this example

Comment: is this correct..?

     if (manager.getInt("limitOfBox") > 0) {
            Bloom.with(this)
                .setParticleRadius(5f)
                .setEffector(
                    BloomEffector.Builder()
                        .setDuration(1500)
                        .setAnchor(
                            (binding.giftImg.width / 2).toFloat(),
                            (binding.giftImg.height / 2).toFloat()
                        )
                        .build()
                )
                .boom(binding.giftImg)

Comment: yeah i think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it` here stands for the view that you want this `Bloom Effect` on.

Refer to the example given by the library itself.

```
 Bloom.with('activity')
 .setParticleRadius(5)
 .setEffector(new BloomEffector.Builder()
     .setDuration(800)
     .setAnchor(view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2)
     .build())
 .boom(view);
```

here view is the item in which the effect is to be created.

Comment: so sir instead of "it" what should i write..? which view?, its my client code so i dont know for what reason he has created that effect? plz can u tell what to write instead of it?

Comment: I suppose you want to create this effect on an image. then use imageView object. Use object of the view that you want to use

Comment: i have updated the old code , plz now can u tell??

Comment: it means binding.giftImg in your old code

Comment: thanks a lot , my issue solved

Answer (score 0):

Where you moved your code from most likely was inside a scope function. We can't tell you what `it` is without you showing us the code in onCreate where you got it from.

A very common scope function is the scope funtion `let`. If you do for example

```
val a = "test"
a.let {
    print(it)
}
```

then `it` refers to the variable `a`. Maybe something like that was used there.

You can read more about scope functions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html)

Comment: i have updated the old code , plz now can u tell??